# Image of the pure braid group under the Artin presentation into the automorphism group of the nilpotent quotient of a free group?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups, braid-groups

As I know, it is unknown that the image of the mapping class group of the surface and its Johnson filtration under the higher Johnson homomorphisms.

There are a relationship between the mapping class group and the pure braid group, which the Johnson homomorphism corresponds to the Milnor's $\bar\mu$-invariant or the Artin representation into not $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ but the automorphism group of free nilpotent quotient $\operatorname{Aut}(F/\gamma_k(F))$ where the lower central series $\gamma_k(F)$ of a free group.

(It is known that the image of the pure braid group under the injective Artin presentation into $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$.)

Then, is it also unknown that what is the image of the pure braid group under the Artin presentations or the Milnor invariants?

Comment: I don't manage to parse the grammar of this question. Perhaps someone who upvoted it can help out?